# Shrink polygon on a particular side using Python

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a polygon geometry (with vertices 1,2,3,4) as shown in the figure below. Now my requirement is that I want to get this polygon shrink/compress to a new polygon (having vertices 1',2',3',4') as shown in the figure below.

(Note vertex 1 = 1' & vertex 2 = 2' in both existing polygon and desired polygon)

My existing polygon (with vertices 1,2,3,4) is having UTM projection.

The figure is as follows:
[image: Fig. showing Existing & desired Polygon]

How can I achieve this programmatically using Python?

Found the solution (coordinates of (x1,y1) & (x2,y2)) using trignometric equations followed by using the concepts of corresponding angles of parallel lines. Please see the below figure:

[image: Updated figure showing the solution]

Comment: What have you tried?  Assuming a rectangle, the same delta would be applied to the X and Y components of P4 and P3, so it's just some soh-cah-toa computational geometry (cosine to X, sine to Y)

Comment: @Vince. I tried trignometric equations of sine & cosine & also used the concepts of corresponding angles between parallel lines to find out the coordinates (x1, y1) & (x2, y2). I had updated my above post where in the uploaded figure I have showed my approach to get coordinates of (x1, y1) & (x2, y2).